# Which Clang compiler should I download?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc, clang

I want to install Clang compliler on my system. I went to [this link](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#2.8), but so many download options out there confused me, as to which version should I download?

I'm using Dell's laptop : Windows 7 Basic 64-bit. I've already installed MinGW version 4.5.0. I've also installed Visual Studio 2008 as well as 2010.

What do you think is the best choice for me? Which Clang should I download? How should I configure it? I'm going to use Clang for the first time. So suggest me the best options!

By the way, can I configure Clang (or Visual Studio) so that Visual Studio may use Clang compiler to compile my C and C++ code?

---

EDIT:

What does it mean when the [download page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#2.8) cryptically says *"Front End Binaries for Mingw32/x86"*?

Comment: And also, why not suggest me the options?

Comment: I would use VS because I have it, it's IDE is easy to get started with and you can get it for free. I don't program in C for Windows though, but I think the old versions of VSC++ compile in C mode (not C++) if the extension is just .c.

Comment: @kenny: With VS, you can configure your project to get compiled in C mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Clang with Visual Studio or MinGW. The choice is yours. But you'll need an external linker to produce Windows executables (MSVS's link.exe or MinGW's ld.exe/g++.exe).

If you want to use MinGW, download the next to last item (frontend binaries to mingw).

You can also compile Clang/LLVM from source, for that see [here](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html). This allows you to try out MSVS or MinGW(-w64). You'll need CMake for the build process.

**UPDATE**: regarding your edit: the "frontend" description reflects either the fact that llvm can be used as a backend in a GCC compilation through llvm-gcc (google has loads of info on this) or the fact that Clang itself is unable to link your code together into an executable or library. You still need the system's linker as I described above.

Comment: By the way, what does it mean to say "using Clang with MinGW"? Using Clang with Visual Studio makes sense to me; by this I understand that I can write my program in Visual Studio, but when I command it to build my project, it will pick Clang compiler to compile my project. But there is no such thing with MinGW. MinGW is compiler itself, not an IDE.

Comment: @Nawaz: I meant MSVC (as in the toolchain, actually only the linker+libraries/headers). If you use MinGW (with their Win32 API headers and libraries), you'd use its linker, `ld.exe`. If you use MSVC with Clang, you'll use MSVC's `link.exe` and the Windows SDK headers and libraries, which are slightly more feature-complete. I don't base my project managament on an IDE, I use a cross-platform build tool (currently CMake or qmake). I use MSVS and MSVC both to designate the toolchain itself, sorry for the confusion. This of course does not mean you can't use the Visual Studio IDE with Clang...

Comment: (continued)  I just fear it won't work as you expect, as MS doesn't care one bit about other compilers. I only know of the Intel compiler that uses MS's build tools. No-one in the MinGW business cares about Visual Studio anyways (if you use GCC, you automatically get pushed to more cross-platform code, or are already coding in a cross-platform manner).

Comment: @rubenvb: that is useful information. thanks. and +1. (God knows what happened to my last upvote! Some problem with my browser,maybe!).

Comment: @Nawaz: thanks! It's probably worth mentioning that Clang on Windows is not quite there yet, but especially the x86 (32-bit) stuff should work decently. x64 is still work in progress.

Comment: @rubenvb: thanks for your time. One last thing I wanted to know, for which I edited my question. Please see it.

Answer (score 2):

Clang [now](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/09/a-path-forward-for-llvm-toolchain-on.html) started releasing [Windows snapshot builds](http://llvm.org/builds/)

Answer (score 1):

None. Front End Binaries @ Mingw32/x86 is close, but you explicitly mentioned Windows 7 Basic 64-bit
so to be very specific you'll avail 64-bit benefits. So you'll follow steps at http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#buildWindows You may get VS2012 Express and the string with CMake should be "Visual Studio 11 Win64" Select Release instead of the default debug configuration from the dropdown and then build. Tool-chains are tightly coupled hierarchy, and MS's indulgence in non-standard extensions was never up-to-date by any other vendor implementation. Till llvm libcpp completes MinGW-W64 is the closest libstdc++ that I got from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/mingw-w64-bin_i686-mingw_20111220.zip/download Check for newer build at http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ Following are my trial calls for Hi console app

clang++.exe -fno-ms-compatibility -fno-use-cxa-atexit   -IC:\mingw\include\c++\4.7.0 -IC:\mingw\include\c++\4.7.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32 -IC:\mingw\include\c++\4.7.0\backward -IC:\mingw\include  -c C:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.cpp -o C:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.o

ld.exe  -oC:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.exe C:\Users\Vipul\Documents\Hello.o  -m i386pep -Bdynamic -Lc:\mingw\lib c:\mingw\lib\crt2.o c:\mingw\lib\crtbegin.o -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -LC:\Windows\SUA\opt\gcc64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-interix6\4.6.0 -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 c:\mingw\lib\crtend.o

The parameters are set on one single occasion of configuring IDE setting for say Code::Blocks The libs to pass to ld linker are determined using -v along-with g++ as clang++ will try to link libc++ sources against VS2012 binaries. Using g++ rather than ld is easier but seldom fails with ld not found internally owing to close coupling of tool-chain by hardcoding tool locations within source.